# Dropbox API get URL for media listing

Tags: dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox REST API, and i am wondering if there is a way to list files in a folder with URL for each file? Or do I have to call the Media endpoint individually for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at their documentation for [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#media).  You would need to loop through a list of files, but this should do the trick.